# Getting an error while "npm install" after deletion of package.lock.json file in the module. [OS - Windows]

Tags: npm, installation, react-redux, dependencies, redux-form-validators

I want to delete `package-lock.json` file in a module and to use npm install. But while npm install running, I got an error saying "unable to resolve dependency tree".

Whole error:
["unable to resolve dependency tree"
while resolving: tpip@0.1.0
Found: react-redux@7.1.0
node_modules/react-redux
react-redux@"7.1.0" from the root project.
could not resolve dependency:
peer react-redux@"^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" from redux-form-validators@2.7.5
node_module/reduxform-validators
redux-formvalidators @"^2.7.5" from the root project
fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with--force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOJH9.png)

I followed more tutorials and documentations. But I could not solve down it.

Answer (score 1):

There are packages which use some other packages. After npm version 7(my guess), they have added this warning. This is just to inform us about those packages.

To resolve it as it is mentioned use `--force`

Whole command:

```
npm install --force
```

This should solve your issue and the project should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have a package that depended on an older version of redux and you have a newer version.
You should use the command:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

The `--legacy-peer-deps` is a way to bypass peerDependency auto-installation, it tells NPM to ignore peer dependencies and proceed with the installation anyway.

Note that this may result in conflicts due to potentially breaking changes